# Undefined is not an object (Evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate) in reactnative

Tags: react-native

Good day.

I tried navigating to another page using reactnative navigation but it is displaying "Undefined is not an object (Evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate) in reactnative"

This is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View, Image, Alert} from 'react-native';
import { Icon, Button, List, ListItem, Left, Thumbnail, Body, Right } from 'native-base'; 
import {styles} from '../../../css/Designs';
import OptionsMenu from "react-native-options-menu";
const myIcon = (<Icon name='more' style={{fontSize:30,color:'#000'}}/>);

export class TheStudent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
};

editItem = (student) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('AllStudents');
}

deleteItem = (student) => {
    Alert.alert(
        '',
        'Delete student?',
        [
            {
                text: 'No',
                onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                style: 'cancel',
            },

            { 
                text: 'Yes', 
                onPress: () => this.deleteTheItem(student)
            },
        ],
        {cancelable: false},
      );
}

deleteTheItem = (student) => {
    alert(student);
}

render() {

    return(

        <List>
            <ListItem avatar>
                <Left>
                    <Thumbnail source={require('../../../img/male_avatar.png')} />
                </Left>
                <Body>
                    <Text style={styles.userName}>{this.props.surname} {this.props.firstname} {this.props.middlename} </Text>
                    <Text>{this.props.matric}    {this.props.level}L   {this.props.phone}</Text>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                    <OptionsMenu
                        customButton={myIcon}
                        options={["Edit", "Delete"]}
                        actions={[this.editItem.bind(this,this.props.id), this.deleteItem.bind(this,this.props.id)]}/>
                </Right>
            </ListItem> 
        </List>
    );
}
}
```

I have been stucked in this for hours and I have tried all the other links I saw on this issue, but all to no avail.
I will be glad if you can be of help.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this class directly referenced in the route configuration object or is it embedded in another object that is? If it's embedded you might have to pass the navigation prop to this class from it's parent.

Comment: That looks like `this.props.navigation` is undefined. Maybe you are not passing the prop you think you are passing. You can try to log the content of your props to check what's in there. In the constructor `console.log(props)`.

Comment: `this.props.navigation` is undefined means you need `withNavigation` HOC, check my answer, please, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your component with the HOC `withNavigation` then the prop will be available in the component, try something like this:

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class TheStudent extends Component {
   ....
}
export withNavigation(TheStudent)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution which @Rachid Rhafour mentioned in his answer.

You can export your component withNavigation which can import from react-navigation.

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class YourClassName extends Component {

}
export withNavigation(YourClassName)
```

Another approach is you can make route file by which you can navigate to any component file without any trouble.

example:
if there is two or three component to navigate or from navigate you should maintain that route by route file.

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import ScreenOne from "./ScreenOne";
import ScreenTwo from "./ScreenTwo";
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: ScreenOne
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ScreenTwo
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```